# To use Spring data Cassandra Reactive or not

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive, spring-data-cassandra

I have the following scenario :

For a given request, we call a function with 2 different sets of parameters. The results from these functions are aggregated and sent as a Map. Function that is called returns a CompletableFuture. Function issues maximum of 4 Async (Listenable Future) cassandra queries. The result from the queries are processed in the order in which they are issued. Based on some conditions the function could return after processing the response from the first query or process all the responses to get the desired result.

## Function

```
@Async
public Map<String,Price> getPricing(String assetType,String code) {
//Issue Query 1 - Returns ListenableFuture
//Issue Query 2 
//Issue Query 3
//Issue Query 4

Query 1 result satisfies return , else continue to Query 2 , followed by 3 and 4.
}
```

## Service

```
public Map<String,Price> getPrice(String assetType) {

CompletableFuture<Map<String,Price>> a = .getPrice(assetType,"A");
CompletableFuture<Map<String,Price>> b = .getPrice(assetType,"B");

//Join A and B and return the result
}
```

Is this a better candidate for Spring Webflux + Reactive Spring data cassandra ? What would be the implementation approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest it is kind of hard to answer without some more details. Mostly what kind of condition the result of the query has to satisfy in order to stop evaluating and return result. The conditional logic is hard when dealing with streams. What you can do is for example:

```
public Mono<Map<String, Person>> findCustomersAndGroupByName(){
    List<String> customer_id = ImmutableList.of("customer id 1", "customer id 2");

    return customerRepo
            .findAllById(customer_id)
            .filter(customer -> customer.getLastname().equals("Smith"))
            .switchIfEmpty(archivedCustomersRepo.findAllById(customer_id)) //if non of the customers has last name smith this will be evaluated
            .filter(customer -> customer.getLastname().equals("Smith"))
            .switchIfEmpty(associatedCustomersRepo.findAllById(customer_id)) //if non of the customers has last name smith this will be evaluated
            .filter(customer -> customer.getLastname().equals("Smith"))
            .collectMap(person -> person.getFirstname()) //grup by first name and return
    ;
```

}

this are all reactive repositories. so they look:

```
public interface ArchivedCustomersRepo extends ReactiveCassandraRepository<Person, String> {}
```

But you have to take in to account that in order to take advantage of reactive approach things have to be reactive (non blocking) all the way. That means also your service (I assume you have rest service response at the end of all of this) has to return mono, flux.

Is is worth it? That depends om the businesses case that you are dealing with. Generally if you have big existing application the answer is no. As there is a big cost in order to shift your mindset (and your colleagues) to more Functional Programming style required by the heavy use of lambda expressions. It took me 2 years.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you . It is a brand new application that has been coded the traditional way, we see response times vary when we issue requests for 50 at a time.. the least being 4 ms and the longest being 20 ms. While these are distributed to multiple instances, the issue is not with Cassandra - it is definitely the way we are processing the responses. Hoping the reactive way allows better utilization of resources

Comment: A it will definitely help. Don't be surprised if the time of execution for individual requests will go up a little bit, around 5-7%. Also use jetty as your server it has much better implementation for reading data from the socket then tomcat. To my knowledge tomcat still uses one thread per request model. I have fully reactive app in production right now so if you need any help let me know.

Comment: thank you. Will definitely reach out to you. Even if I get it working fine - which I think I am half way through , I would still love to get it reviewed. Appreciate your help !

Comment: I am able to get started and have been able to get it working. Not sure what I am doing is right, when we have to execute some calls in parallel, while we need to have some in sequence. I posted a question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54281833/reactor-mono-execute-parallel-tasks

Comment: I answered in the relevant thread. Let me know if you have any more questions.